# Does Silverlight download third party libraries if assemlby .dll is added to project?

Tags: silverlight

Lets say you have a simple Silverlight application online (Website) with 200 KByte. If someone visits my website he/she has to download those 200 KByte .

What happens if i use, in my code, some third party libraries, like JSON.net or Dotnetzip? If i use a library and that .dll is 500 KByte big, does the user have to download the whole 700 Kbyte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight packages everything, entirely in it's XAP file which it creates. So anything you include in the project is packaged in that. Any third party .dlls, any embedded fonts, virtually everything.

So, as you have asked, yes, your users will download the entire XAP of 700kb and their browsers will un-pack and use them. :)

Hope this solves your query.